# Stackengine centering problem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, stackengine

I have a problem centering text with `stackengine` stacks. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\Shortstack[c]{Cognicion abstractiva}
\end{document}
```

The result is this:
[image]

(I measured the distances with Adobe Acrobat Pro.)

As you can see, the two texts fail to be centred. I noticed this behavior in all cases I use `\Shortstack`. Is this normal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are just not taking account of sidebearings of the characters so the actual character widths used for centering include some white space. TeX has no information about the glyph shape, it can not tell what parts of a specified character width are black.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}

$\left|\Shortstack[c]{Cognicion abstractiva}\right|$


$\left|\Shortstack[c]{\frame{Cognicion} \frame{abstractiva}}\right|$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `\frame` equivalent to `fbox`?

Comment: @NVaughan `\frame` is more or less `\fbox` with `\fboxsep` set to 0pt but it's from picture mode so the line thickness depends on \thinlines, \thicklines rather than \fboxrule

Answer (score 8):

This example should lift any doubt about what to measure; note that in the first two cases the hairlines are perfectly superimposed to each other, showing that there's no issue with `\Shortstack`.

On the other hand, the difference you measured is less than 0.4pt, too small to be really noticeable: it depends on the bounding boxes of the characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\hairline}[1][black]{%
  \leavevmode\kern-0.05pt
  \smash{\color{#1}\vrule height 20pt depth 20pt width 0.1pt}%
  \kern-0.05pt
}
\begin{document}
\centering
\Shortstack[c]{\hairline{}XXXXXX\hairline{} XXXXXXXXXX}

\hairline{}XXXXXX\hairline{}\\ XXXXXXXXXX

\vspace{20pt}

\Shortstack[c]{%
  \hairline[red]Cognicion\hairline[red]
  \hairline[green]abstractiva\hairline[green]%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. BTW, could you please explain to me the `\hairline` macro?

Comment: @NVaughan I insert a rule that extends above and below the baseline by 20pt, occupying no horizontal space, because of the two kerns that kill the rule width; it takes no vertical space either, because of `\smash`. The `\leavevmode` is for ensuring the kern and `\smash` are seen when we're already typesetting a paragraph (so in horizontal mode).