# Horizontally centering glyph over text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, stackengine

In the given MWE, note that the new `slur` command is not centered with the two Fs that it connects.

I've tried adjusting the `scale` of `lilyGlyph`, but it remains too far left. I would like the ends of the `slur` to be centered with either F. But if it's not *too* difficult, I'd also like to see how one could make the ends centered with the entire `F$^x$` unit.

`\stackon` from the `stackengine` package may be helpful, as shown in [Two-lined text (text over text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130865/two-lined-text-text-over-text) (see also [Stackengine centering problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311354/stackengine-centering-problem)). I've supplied an attempt at the bottom of the MWE, but it's still not adequately centered, nor can I find a way to lower it.

(And for anyone curious, this is for a particular type of musical notation.)

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand{\slur}{%
    \scalebox{2}[1]{%
        \rotatebox{180}{\lilyGlyph[scale=1.5,raise=-2.0]{ties.lyric.default}}%
            }%
        \phantom{\textendash}%
        }

\begin{document}
G$^2$--F$^2$\slur F$^1$--E$^1$

G$^2$--\stackon{F$^2$\phantom{\textendash}F$^1$}{\scalebox{2}[1]{\rotatebox{180}{\lilyGlyph[scale=1.5]{ties.lyric.default}}}}--E$^1$
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did not manage to install `lilyglphys`, but would note that `\stackon` takes an optional length argument to denote the stacking gap, as in `\stackon[1pt]{}{}`, which you can use to lower the glyph.  In a case like this, I would tend to employ the `useanchorwidth` setting, as well, thus `\stackengine{1pt}{...}{...}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}`  You can make the slur wider by increasing the `{2}` following `\scalebox`.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the stacking gap, the horizontal scale of the slur, and added a small kern.  I also used the full `\stackengine` macro to readily obtain the "useanchorwidth" setting as true.

I put it in a macro, with an optional argument, that determines a horizontal scaling.

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\slur[3][3.5]{%
\stackengine{-.5pt}{#2\phantom{\textendash}#3}%
  {\scalebox{#1}[1]{\rotatebox{180}%
  {\lilyGlyph[scale=1.5]{ties.lyric.default}}}\kern1pt}%
  {O}{c}{F}{T}{S}
}

\begin{document}
G$^2$--\slur{F$^2$}{F$^1$}--E$^1$

G$^2$--\slur[2.4]{F}{G}--E$^1$
\end{document}
```

[image]